# android.view.InflateException error as crash report from users. What could be the cause?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, android-studio-3.0

Any idea why I would be getting this error:

```
android.view.InflateException
```

keithcolclough.stonestokilograms.stonetokilogramsconverter.MainActivity.onCreate
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException:

```
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at keithcolclough.stonestokilograms.stonetokilogramsconverter.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:268)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
```

Here is the XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Enter the amount you want to convert"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_text_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/stoneText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Amount in Stone"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/KgText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Amount in KG"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/convertToKgButton" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2327915784489185/1078421100"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/convertToStoneButton"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="imageClick"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fitness" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertToKgButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:onClick="convertStoneClick"
        android:text="Convert to KG"
        android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stoneText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertToStoneButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:onClick="convertKgClick"
        android:text="Convert to Stone"
        android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/KgText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="513dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="199dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/tipButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="hintClick"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/convertToStoneButton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/questionmark" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the main activity code.

package keithcolclough.stonestokilograms.stonetokilogramsconverter;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;



    // An app that converts stones and KG weights for the user.
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toast myToast;

    public void hintClick(View view){

        // Play a pop noise to signal button has been clicked
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
        mp.start();

        //Picks a random number a then pops a random toast depending on that number
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (randomNum == 1) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "The average man weighs 195 pounds (88KG)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 2) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "The average woman weighs 168 pounds (76KG)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 3) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "One study showed that short sleep was linked to 89% increased risk of obesity in children, and 55% in adults.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 4) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Studies show that people who eat the most fish have a lower risk of all sorts of diseases, including heart disease, dementia and depression.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 5) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Coffee is high in antioxidants, and studies show that coffee drinkers live longer, and have a reduced risk of type 2 diabetes.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 6) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Despite being high in fat, nuts are incredibly nutritious and healthy.\nThey are loaded with magnesium, vitamin E, fiber and various other nutrients.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 7) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "A good way to improve gut health, is to eat probiotic foods (like live yogurt and sauerkraut), take probiotic supplements, and eat plenty of fiber.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 8) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "The best time to drink water is half an hour before meals. One study showed that half a liter of water, 30 minutes before each meal, increased weight loss by 44%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 9) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Studies show that people who eat the most vegetables and fruits live longer, and have a lower risk of heart disease, type 2 diabetes and obesity.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else if (randomNum == 10) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "A high protein intake can boost metabolism significantly, while making you feel so full that you automatically eat fewer calories.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
        else {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Extra virgin olive oil is the healthiest fat on the planet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
        }
    }


    public void imageClick(View view) {

        //Picks a random number a then applys a random image depending on that number
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomImage = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (randomImage == 1) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 2) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness2);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 3) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness3);
        }
        else {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness4);
        }
    }


    // Code for when a user has entered a stone value and clicks the button to convert to KG.
    public void convertStoneClick(View view) {

        // Play a pop noise to signal button has been clicked
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
        mp.start();

        // Closes the keyboard after a user has clicked the convert button
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        // Changes the picture at the top of the screen
        //Picks a random number a then applies a random image depending on that number
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomImage = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (randomImage == 1) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 2) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness2);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 3) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness3);
        }
        else {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness4);
        }

        // Initialize stoneText variable with the amount the user has entered as their stone value.
        EditText stoneText = findViewById(R.id.stoneText);

        // Converts stones to KG, or brings up a error toast for the user if they did not enter numbers.
        try {
            String amountInStone = stoneText.getText().toString();
            double amountInKgDouble = Double.parseDouble(amountInStone) * 6.35029;
            String amountinKgString = String.format(Locale.UK,"%.1f", amountInKgDouble);

            // Pops up a toast displaying the conversion.
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, amountInStone + " stone, is " + amountinKgString + " KG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
            // Deletes the text from the editText so the user can more efficiently enter a new value.
            //stoneText.getText().clear();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter numbers only!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
            stoneText.getText().clear();
        }
    }

    // Code for when a user has entered a kg value and clicks the button to convert to stone.
    public void convertKgClick(View view) {

        // Play a pop noise to signal button has been clicked
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pop);
        mp.start();

        // Closes the keyboard after a user has clicked the convert button
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        // Changes the picture at the top of the screen
        //Picks a random number a then applys a random image depending on that number
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomImage = rand.nextInt((4 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (randomImage == 1) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 2) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness2);
        }
        else if (randomImage == 3) {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness3);
        }
        else {
            ImageButton image = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fitness4);
        }

        // Initialize kgText variable with the amount the user has entered as their KG value.
        EditText kgText = findViewById(R.id.KgText);

        // Converts KG to stone, or brings up a error toast for the user if they did not enter numbers.
        try {
            String amountInKg = kgText.getText().toString();
            double amountInStoneDouble = Double.parseDouble(amountInKg) / 6.35029;
            String amountinStoneString = String.format(Locale.UK,"%.1f", amountInStoneDouble);

            // Pops up a toast displaying the conversion result.
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, amountInKg + " KG, is " + amountinStoneString + " Stone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
            // Deletes the editText so the user can more efficiently enter a new value.
            //kgText.getText().clear();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            if (myToast != null) {
                myToast.cancel();
            }
            myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter numbers only!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            myToast.show();
            kgText.getText().clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Ensures when the user first starts the app that the keyboard will not pop up.
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        // Initialize and load an advert
        AdView mAdView;
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-2327915784489185~3045931288");
        // Test ad unit (Use when testing app)
        //  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
        // Real ad unit (Use for release)
        // ca-app-pub-2327915784489185/1078421100
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Opening welcome Toast for the user.
        if (myToast != null) {
            myToast.cancel();
        }
        myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to the converter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        myToast.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()    {
        // If app is destroyed any toasts will be stop displaying.
        myToast.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        // If app is stopped any toasts will be stop displaying.
        super.onStop();
        myToast.cancel();
    }
}
```

So it seems the error is happening when the application is started. But not for all users. I have had others test it out and it worked fine, but some users are not able to open the app.

Apologies if my formatting isn't perfect I am fairly new to coding, and also to stackoverflow.

I can not seem to produce this error myself but from the google play store crash report this is what it says....

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3253)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:551)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:380)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at keithcolclough.stonestokilograms.stonetokilogramsconverter.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:268)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:794)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:716)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:847)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:855)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:810)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:527)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:2558)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:100)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes (AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init> (AppCompatImageButton.java:78)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init> (AppCompatImageButton.java:68)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton (AppCompatViewInflater.java:201)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:758)
```

Comment: There should be more to the stack trace, such as 1+ separate "Caused by:" sections with trace lines.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've added the full log that the Google Play Store gives. I can't replicate this error myself so don't have a logcat of info.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed to fix it!

I finally managed to get the error to appear for me and the way I fixed it was re-importing all the drawable images and putting them in the regular drawable folder rather then the v24 folder.

It now runs smoothly.